# PyZMQ user input() in PAIR/PAIR communication archetype

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using PyZMQ to create a simple PAIR/PAIR communication archetype messaging pattern.

#### PairServer

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "9999"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
print("Binding socket to port: " + str(port))
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
print("Connection has been established")

while True:
    data = input("Enter: ")
    socket.send_string(data)
    msg = str(socket.recv(), "utf-8")
    print("Received: ",msg)
    time.sleep(2)
```

#### PairClient

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "9999"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
print("Connecting socket to port: " + str(port))
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
print("Connected")

count = 0
response = 1

while True:
    msg = str(socket.recv(), "utf-8")
    print("Received: ",msg)
    count = count + 1
    print("Counter: ",count)

    if count == response:
        data = "Client has received message from server: " + msg
        socket.send_string(data)
        response = response + 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

I am not able to send user input from server to client as nothing transmits when I press enter but am able to send and receive hard coded messages from server to client. When I do, messages received from the server side will sometimes be received on the client side. I am unsure whether this is due to the fact that both scripts are being run on localhost and there is a conflict within the socket.

For example,

#### PairServer

```
data = "random data"
```

#### PairClient

Output:

```
Received:  random data
Counter:  4
Received:  Client has received message from server: random data
Received:  random data
Counter:  5
Received:  random data
Counter:  6
```

How do I send user input and prevent received messages from client to server to be received by the client on localhost(if that is the issue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the **`input()`** issue. I realised that Sublime3 cannot run input commands. I have fixed this by installing the SublimeREPL package.

Although I still have no concrete idea why sometimes received messages from client to server are received by the client on localhost.